# Convert an int into a 4 byte char array in C

Tags: c, arrays, char, byte

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting an int into a 4 byte char array (C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784263/converting-an-int-into-a-4-byte-char-array-c)

Using the Dynamic C program (the language is C), I am trying to convert an int into an array of bytes 4 places long. So far I have looked online and I have found a few examples. However, none seem to work for me. I have had an ongoing problem where the correct byte numbers are printed, but they are repeated twice for some reason. I have provided the code below:

```
void main(){
 int a=1379;
 int i=0;
 unsigned char value [4];

value[3] = (byte) (a & (0xFF));
value[2] = (byte) ((a >> 8) & 0xFF);
value[1] = (byte) ((a >> 16) & 0xFF);
value[0] = (byte) ((a >> 24) & 0xFF);
//convert int values to bytes by placing them in a char buffer

for(i=0;i<4;i++){
 printf("%d",value[i]);
 printf(", ");
 }
printf("\n");
}
```

For example, with this value the program prints "5, 99, 5, 99," when it should print "0, 0, 5, 99". Thank you for your help.

Comment: There's something you're not telling us.

Comment: I'm thinking it's a language (for microcontrollers) that has 16-bit ints.

Comment: You should initialise your array, `unsigned char value[4] = {0};`.

Comment: Builds and runs fine here, with the expected result. Changed the byte casts to char though, since there's no byte in linux gcc.

Comment: @pstrjds -- Just because the title's the same does not make it a dupe.

Comment: What do you get when you write `printf("%d\n", sizeof(int));`?  Have you tried using `uint32_t` instead of `int`?

Comment: 1) main should return int 2) remove the (byte) casts (what is byte?) they can only do harm. 3) shifting signed ints will sign-extend them, use preferrably unsigned entities to shift. 4) use %u printf format to print unsigned types.  5) you are assuming 32 bits ints, and CHAR_BIT=8. 6) sizeof is your friend.

Comment: `byte` is not a standard C type

Comment: @HotLicks - Not basing off of title, basing off of what is being done, that other question covers this same ground, converting an int into a char array.

Comment: @pstrjds -- But the other question doesn't answer this one.

Comment: 'You should initialise your array' -- no, it's pointless and useless to do that.

Comment: @wildplasser: Actually `"%u"` is specifically for `unsigned int`. On most implementations, `unsigned char` promotes to `int`, so `"%d"` is correct. For 100% portability, cast to `unsigned int` and use `"%u"` -- or use `"%hhu"` (added in C99).

Comment: You're assuming that `int` is 4 bytes. You should at least document that assumption.

Comment: @KeithThompson. Thanks. Yes, I know about the default promotions, but I tend to be careful with vararg functions. My answer below casts to (unsigned int), which still is not necessary.

Comment: @wildplasser: In fact, it is necessary, or at least a good idea. As I said, `char` promotes to `int` (except on exotic systems where plain `char` is unsigned and `CHAR_MAX > INT_MAX`). Passing an `int` argument for a `"%u"` format is ok in certain circumstances (due to a special-case guarantee about the relationship between `int` and `unsigned int`, though some readings of the literal wording of the standard say it's not safe), but I consider it poor style.

Comment: BTW the char array in the OP was explicitely unsigned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's almost certainly the case that "Dynamic C" is an implementation with an `int` of 16 bits, which is perfectly "legal" for C.  If the `int` is 16 bits, any shift over 16 bits is modulo-16, so the second two shifts duplicate the first two.

Comment: +1 since this is either the answer OR it is a duplicate question :)

Comment: For further info, based on this page [http://www.rabbitsemiconductor.com.cn/products/dc/index.shtml](http://www.rabbitsemiconductor.com.cn/products/dc/index.shtml) mentioning dynamic c 32, I would guess that dynamic c has 16 bit `int`

Comment: @pstrjds It's not a duplicate question at all. The other question doesn't mention the behavior this one does, behavior that indicates a 16-bit machine.

Comment: @JimBalter - I added the smily face to point out that I was making a poor joke. I realized after reading further it was not a duplicate and was responding to Hot Licks that I had realized that and upvoted his correct answer.

Comment: I believe its actually UB to shift by more than the length of the variable, may be worth saying this. The compiler probably just happens to do something sensible.

Comment: @Vality - Well, it *used* to be that the shift was *defined* to be modulo the word length, but I can't guess how the standard might have changed since I last helped create a C compiler about 15 years ago.  (I remember because it was a minor PITA to implement this, since the "natural" thing would be to just shift away the significance.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy the bits from your int variable into the char-array. You can simply do that with `memcpy` like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void split(int val, unsigned char *arr) {
    memcpy(arr, &val, sizeof(int));
}

int main() {
    unsigned char bytes[4];
    split(1379, bytes);
    printf("%d, %d, %d, %d\n", bytes[0], bytes[1], bytes[2], bytes[3]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
 int a=1379;
 unsigned bot,top ;
 unsigned char value [sizeof a];

 memcpy (value, &a, sizeof value);

 /* You can omit this loop if you are on a big-endian machine */
#if LITTLE_ENDIAN
 for (bot =0, top = sizeof value; --top > bot; bot++) {
    unsigned char tmp;
    tmp = value[bot];
    value [bot] = value[top];
    value[top] = tmp;
    }
#endif

for(bot=0;bot < sizeof value;bot++){
 printf("%u", (unsigned int) value[bot]);
 printf(", ");
 }
printf("\n");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code makes no assumptions about the sizes of ints or characters; that's why there are no manifest constants left in it. (and gcc unrolls the "silly" loop, anyway)