# Converting 32 bit number to four 8bit numbers

Tags: c, bit, 32-bit

I am trying to convert the input from a device (always integer between 1 and 600000) to four 8-bit integers.

For example,

If the input is 32700, I want `188 127 00 00`.

I achieved this by using:

```
32700 % 256 
32700 / 256
```

The above works till 32700. From 32800 onward, I start getting incorrect conversions.

I am totally new to this and would like some help to understand how this can be done properly.

Comment: Are you sure it really is _from 32800 onward_ or is it actually from 32768?

Comment: You are right!! I guess you see the issue.....tell me tell me...

Comment: Is that `%` a typo? I'd expect `MOD 256` to get you the 188 and `/256` to get you the 127. The confusing part is that `%` is the C operator for taking modulo, which surely you mean by `MOD`. I.e. to me the two lines you show are semantically identical. Please show the result you get for the two lines. Which one gets you the desired 188, which the 127?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I have edited the question.

Comment: Also, I realised that 32767 is the upper limit for int. Changing to long to see if things get better.

Comment: `600000) to a 32 bit signed integer.` I do not understand. A number `32700` by itself is  already a 32-bit signed integer. `input is 32700, I want 188 127 00 00` that is converting a signed 32-bit integer into four 8-bit integers. `I achieved this by using:` I do not understand, that's just two numbers. `I start getting incorrect conversions` If you are having problems with some actual code, instead of explaining, please _show the code_. Please post an [MCVE]. Code speaks 1000 words. Your description may be completely unrelated to the problem you are facing.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I want to convert the integer to four 8-bit integers

Comment: I will edit the question to reflect this

Comment: `I start getting incorrect conversions` What architecture, compiler, compiler version and compiler options are you using? How are you checking that? On what operating system/environment are you executing your program? How are you "observing" that an incorrect conversion has been made? With a terminal output, something prints on your printer, you read a value with your debugger? [How do we ask a good question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I think related: [converting an int to 4 byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784263/converting-an-int-into-a-4-byte-char-array-c)

Comment: Okay let me read the guidelines.

Comment: You are right. I wonder if this is a commonly used operation in this field? I am just trying to figure out how to write a small C program to achieve this.

Comment: An answer below talks about casting it using the int32_t type. Trying to find the header file for that

Comment: @AmanKejriwal ``32700 % 256`` explains how you get 188 //ly 127. But how do you get last two zeros? Are they always zero?

Comment: Yes they always 00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
unsigned char bytes[4];
unsigned long n;

n = (unsigned long) sensore1 * 100;

bytes[0] = n & 0xFF;     
bytes[1] = (n >> 8) & 0xFF;
bytes[2] = (n >> 16) & 0xFF;
bytes[3] = (n >> 24) & 0xFF;
       CAN_WRITE(0x7FD,8,01,sizeof(n),bytes[0],bytes[1],bytes[2],bytes[3],07,255);
```

Comment: Use `uint32_t` instead of `unsigned long`

Answer (score 5):

Major edit following clarifications:

Given that someone has already mentioned the shift-and-mask approach (which is undeniably the right one), I'll give another approach, which, to be pedantic, is not portable, machine-dependent, and possibly exhibits undefined behavior. It is nevertheless a good learning exercise, IMO.

For various reasons, your computer represents integers as groups of 8-bit values (called *bytes*); note that, although extremely common, this is not *always* the case (see `CHAR_BIT`). For this reason, values that are represented using more than 8 bits use multiple bytes (hence those using a number of bits with is a multiple of 8). For a 32-bit value, you use 4 bytes and, in memory, those bytes always follow each other.

We call a *pointer* a value containing the address in memory of another value. In that context, a *byte* is defined as the smallest (in terms of bit count) value that can be referred to by a pointer. For example, your 32-bit value, covering 4 bytes, will have 4 "addressable" cells (one per byte) and its address is defined as the first of those addresses:

```
|==================|
| MEMORY | ADDRESS |
|========|=========|
|  ...   |   x-1   | <== Pointer to byte before
|--------|---------|
| BYTE 0 |    x    | <== Pointer to first byte (also pointer to 32-bit value)
|--------|---------|
| BYTE 1 |   x+1   | <== Pointer to second byte
|--------|---------|
| BYTE 2 |   x+2   | <== Pointer to third byte
|--------|---------|
| BYTE 3 |   x+3   | <== Pointer to fourth byte
|--------|---------|
|  ...   |   x+4   | <== Pointer to byte after
|===================
```

So what you want to do (split the 32-bit word into 8-bits word) has already been done by your computer, as it is imposed onto it by its processor and/or memory architecture. To reap the benefits of this almost-coincidence, we are going to find where your 32-bit value is stored and read its memory *byte-by-byte* (instead of 32 bits at a time).

As all serious SO answers seem to do so, let me cite the Standard (ISO/IEC 9899:2018, 6.2.5-20) to define the last thing I need (emphasis mine):

> Any number of derived types can be constructed from the object and function types, as follows:
>
> - An *array type* describes a **contiguously** allocated nonempty set of objects with a particular member object type, called the *element type*. [...] Array types are characterized by their element type and by the number of elements in the array. [...]
> - [...]

So, as elements in an array are defined to be contiguous, a 32-bit value in memory, on a machine with 8-bit bytes, really is nothing more, in its machine representation, than an array of 4 bytes!

Given a 32-bit signed value:

```
int32_t value;
```

its address is given by `&value`. Meanwhile, an array of 4 8-bit bytes may be represented by:

```
uint8_t arr[4];
```

notice that I use the unsigned variant because those bytes don't really represent a number *per se* so interpreting them as "signed" would not make sense. Now, a pointer-to-array-of-4-`uint8_t` is defined as:

```
uint8_t (*ptr)[4];
```

and if I assign the address of our 32-bit value to such an array, I will be able to index each byte individually, which means that I will be reading the byte directly, avoiding any pesky shifting-and-masking operations!

```
uint8_t (*bytes)[4] = (void *) &value;
```

I need to cast the pointer ("`(void *)`") because <s>I can't bear that whining compiler</s> `&value`'s type is "pointer-to-`int32_t`" while I'm assigning it to a "pointer-to-array-of-4-`uint8_t`" and this type-mismatch is caught by the compiler and pedantically warned against by the Standard; this is a first warning that what we're doing is not ideal!

Finally, we can access each byte individually *by reading it directly from memory* through indexing: `(*bytes)[n]` reads the `n`-th byte of `value`!

To put it all together, given a `send_can(uint8_t)` function:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(*bytes); i++)
    send_can((*bytes)[i]);
```

and, for testing purpose, we define:

```
void send_can(uint8_t b)
{
    printf("%hhu\n", b);
}
```

which prints, on my machine, when `value` is `32700`:

```
188
127
0
0
```

Lastly, this shows yet another reason why this method is platform-dependent: the order in which the bytes of the 32-bit word is stored isn't *always* what you would expect from a theoretical discussion of binary representation *i.e*:

- byte 0 contains bits 31-24
- byte 1 contains bits 23-16
- byte 2 contains bits 15-8
- byte 3 contains bits 7-0

actually, AFAIK, the C Language permits *any* of the 24 possibilities for ordering those 4 bytes (this is called *endianness*). Meanwhile, shifting and masking will always get you the `n`-th "logical" byte.

Comment: I get the value as a number from a linear sensor based on the device position.

Comment: My taks is to take this number and convery it into a 32-bit signed integer representation to be sent over to a display unit using a CAN message

Comment: so you have to split a 32-bit number in 8-bit "packets"? I'm not familiar with the CAN protocol... That would explain the modulus though. Be careful about endianess!

Comment: Right I have to use little-edien

Comment: issue is that this is not my primary field either and I am just doing it for my kid's RC plane controller :D

Answer (score 4):

It really depends on how your architecture stores an int. For example

1. 8 or 16 bit system short=16, int=16, long=32
2. 32 bit system, short=16, int=32, long=32
3. 64 bit system, short=16, int=32, long=64

This is not a hard and fast rule - you need to check your architecture first.  There is also a long long but some compilers do not recognize it and the size varies according to architecture.

Some compilers have uint8_t etc defined so you can actually specify how many bits your number is instead of worrying about ints and longs.

Having said that you wish to convert a number into 4 8 bit ints.  You could have something like

```
unsigned long x = 600000UL;  // you need UL to indicate it is unsigned long
unsigned int b1 = (unsigned int)(x & 0xff);
unsigned int b2 = (unsigned int)(x >> 8) & 0xff;
unsigned int b3 = (unsigned int)(x >> 16) & 0xff;
unsigned int b4 = (unsigned int)(x >> 24);
```

Using shifts is a lot faster than multiplication, division or mod.  This depends on the endianess you wish to achieve.  You could reverse the assignments using b1 with the formula for b4 etc.

Comment: the "faster" comment is not accurate; the compiler should choose the best option , and right-shift is defined as division by two anyway

Comment: I haven't examined the code generated by compilers lately.    The ones I did look at went through the whole modulo/division process instead of shifting but that was over 15 years ago.  Code generators may have moved on since then.

Comment: @cup why do you have to make explicit that the 60.000 is a signed long when it’s being stored at an unsigned long variable?

Answer (score 0):

You could do some bit masking.

600000 is 0x927C0

`600000 / (256 * 256)` gets you the 9, no masking yet.
`((600000 / 256) & (255 * 256)) >> 8` gets you the 0x27 == 39. Using a 8bit-shifted mask of 8 set bits `(256 * 255)` and a right shift by 8 bits, the `>> 8`, which would also be possible as another `/ 256`.
`600000 % 256` gets you the 0xC0 == 192 as you did it. Masking would be `600000 & 255`.

Answer (score 0):

I have been in a similar kind of situation while packing and unpacking huge custom packets of data to be transmitted/received, I suggest you try below approach:

```
typedef union 
{
   uint32_t u4_input;
   uint8_t  u1_byte_arr[4];
}UN_COMMON_32BIT_TO_4X8BIT_CONVERTER;

UN_COMMON_32BIT_TO_4X8BIT_CONVERTER un_t_mode_reg;
un_t_mode_reg.u4_input = input;/*your 32 bit input*/
// 1st byte = un_t_mode_reg.u1_byte_arr[0];
// 2nd byte = un_t_mode_reg.u1_byte_arr[1];
// 3rd byte = un_t_mode_reg.u1_byte_arr[2];
// 4th byte = un_t_mode_reg.u1_byte_arr[3];
```

Answer (score -1):

The largest positive value you can store in a 16-bit signed int is 32767. If you force a number bigger than that, you'll get a *negative* number as a result, hence unexpected values returned by `%` and `/`.

Use either unsigned 16-bit int for a range up to 65535 or a 32-bit integer type.