# How can I store a signed short integer in buffer? C

Tags: c, winapi, network-programming

I need to send a signed short integer but the `sendto` function requires me to give a char buffer.

The buffer: `char SendBuffer[1024];`

I was thinking of making the integer into a string and storing it like that but I am wondering if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting an int into a 4 byte char array (C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784263/converting-an-int-into-a-4-byte-char-array-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this is the declaration of sendto():

```
ssize_t sendto(int sockfd, const void *buf, size_t len, int flags,
                  const struct sockaddr *dest_addr, socklen_t addrlen);
```

The buffer is of type void* so you can pass it a pointer to any type of variable.

In your case:

```
short your_variable;
short *buffer = &your_variable;

sendto(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(your_variable), flags, ...);
```

Comment: why not simple `sendto(sockfd, &your_variable, sizeof(your_variable), flags, ...);`. What is the purpose of the `buffer`?

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland it's the same, I just wanted to make it more explicit

Answer (score 1):

As you did not provide any code you have two options.

I assume that function `sendto` was declared as:

```
int sendto(const void *buff, size_t len);
```

You have two options:

1. Do not copy or convert anything:

```
short x;

/* some code */

sendto(&x, sizeof(x));
```

You may copy the context of the x to char buffer by using `memcpy`

```
memcpy(SendBuff, &x sizeof(x));
sendto(SendBuff, sizeof(x));
```

Comment: better is to use the standard htons function.